# Is there a way to print stack trace on demand?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

I am looking for a way to get a stack trace when I am at a certain breakpoint. Is this possible? Ideally without having to crash the application and modifying the code. I tried playing with the Android debugger but couldn't find anything very helpful.

The reason is that sometimes I am not certain how the application arrived at a point in code, so I am open to other suggestions that would help me trace the method calls.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This can be done in Java:

```
new Throwable().printStackTrace();
```

In Eclipse, if you create an "expression" with that code in the `Expressions` view of `Debug` perspective, it will print current stack trace (i.e. the stacktrace of the breakpoint your code stopped on) in the `Console` view.

Comment: Thanks, do you mean in the Expressions view? What code should I put in, the one on the line with the breakpoint? I tried, but nothing appeared neither in the console view nor in the LogCat.

Comment: In the "Expressions" view, click "Add new expression" and paste the code I provided (`new Throwable().printStackTrace();`). Hit `Enter`. Switch to "Console" view and you should see a stacktrace.

This works for me on vanilla Eclipse Juno, debugging simple Java app with just a `main(String[])` method.

Comment: Oh, sure, I was just being dense :-) It should have occured to me that I want to let execute the code you posted. Thanks a lot, works like a charm.

Answer (score 4):

```
Log.e("AppName", "Debug exception", new Exception());
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to throw an exception, immediately catch it and use `printStackTrace()`.

You could also try `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()` which gives you a `StackTraceElement[]` in case you want to to anything else besides having the textual representation that `printStackTrace()` does.

Comment: You do not have to throw it. See my answer ;-)

Comment: Very true, I always forget that :D